# lme4::lmer - Error in if (any(bgrad < 0)) when using random slopes

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to run a linear mixed-effects model for the first time in R, using the `lmer` function from `lme4` package, and I keep getting errors that I don't know how to interpret.

Now, I got the error:

> Error in if (any(bgrad < 0)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

and when I tried to look up online what it means, I read that it has to do with an if-clause, but since I didn't write the code, I don't know how to solve (or even understand) this.

My model looks like this :

```r
lmer(accuracy ~ emotion1 + Age + (1|item) + 
     (1|id) + (1+emotion1|item) + (1+Age|id), data = lib4)
```

and it works if I leave out the random slopes, but I think I need them ?

For a short explanation, I want to see how much age and different emotions influence the accuracy of judgment about the items, while I assume that both items and individuals also have their own intercepts and slopes (some items are easier to evaluate, and some individuals are better at evaluations ; each item might be impacted differently by emotions, and each individual by age?). If my model does not reflect these ideas or doesn't make sense as it is, please let me know too! As I say, I'm new to mixed effects models.

I don't know if this is a question for which you need to see my data, I'll send it to you if you do.

Comment: for anyone to help further please share your exact code and data (or a replica data set that shows the problem). what is bgrad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to know this, but the error occurs [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/9c673edb76ae19165ffe0a45b375737bb02f1fc3/R/modular.R#L615) (go to https://github.com/lme4/lme4 and search for "bgrad").

I have not seen this particular error before (which is impressive since I've been hearing about `lme4` errors for quite a while now).

The thing that's obviously wrong (sorry) but easy to fix is that your random effect specification `(1|item) + (1|id) + (1+emotion1|item) + (1+Age|id)` is redundant; the random-slopes specifications `(1+emotion1|item)` and `(1+Age|id)` already include the intercept terms (and unlike base-R `[g]lm` formulas, the package isn't quite smart enough to drop these redundant terms automatically). Try rewriting your model without `(1|item)` and `(1|id)` and see if that clears things up.

[This open issue](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/625) suggests that `lmer` should try to check for/warn in these cases.

That said, I would be interested in seeing the data for a reproducible example so that (hopefully) a more useful error message can be given.

Comment: Thank you, the error message went away after I solved the redundancy as you said ! To be honest I'm not exactly sure how you share data here, do I have to upload it somewhere else and give you a link ?

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it. If you want you can do a web search and find my e-mail address easily; just send me the data.